# Display data from database table into a html table using php

Tags: php, html, image

I have a table named Produit in my database "enchere".

I would like to display data stored in the table produit. these data are Nom_produit, description_produit and the image of the product.

the image is stored in a server ( in my machine, I am testing my code with Xampp).

I get all the data and are displayed. The problem is the image can not be displayed. I tried to make sure that the URL of the image is correctly typed and I could'nt fix the probelem. Any help please
A screenshot of my web page is attached , no image displayed
below is my code .

```
$conn=new mysqli('localhost','root','','enchere');
if (!$conn) {
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());  
}

$sql = "select * from produit ";

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$query) {
    die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
//$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
//echo "127.0.0.1/images/".$row['image'];
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Displaying MySQL Data in HTML Table</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-size: 15px;
            color: #343d44;
            font-family: "segoe-ui", "open-sans", tahoma, arial;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        table {
            margin: auto;
            font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe Ui";
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        h1 {
            margin: 25px auto 0;
            text-align: center;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-size: 17px;
        }

        table td {
            transition: all .5s;
        }

        /* Table */
        .data-table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            font-size: 14px;
            min-width: 537px;
        }

        .data-table th, 
        .data-table td {
            border: 1px solid #e1edff;
            padding: 7px 17px;
        }
        .data-table caption {
            margin: 7px;
        }

        /* Table Header */
        .data-table thead th {
            background-color: #508abb;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            border-color: #6ea1cc !important;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        /* Table Body */
        .data-table tbody td {
            color: #353535;
        }
        .data-table tbody td:first-child,
        .data-table tbody td:nth-child(4),
        .data-table tbody td:last-child {
            text-align: right;
        }

        .data-table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {
            background-color: #f4fbff;
        }
        .data-table tbody tr:hover td {
            background-color: #ffffa2;
            border-color: #ffff0f;
        }

        /* Table Footer */
        .data-table tfoot th {
            background-color: #e5f5ff;
            text-align: right;
        }
        .data-table tfoot th:first-child {
            text-align: left;
        }
        .data-table tbody td:empty
        {
            background-color: #ffcccc;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>VALIDATION DES PRODUITS AJOUTES</h1>
    <table class="data-table">
        <caption class="title">Produit en attente Validation administrateur</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nom_Produit</th>
                <th>Description_Produit</th>
                <th>Prix_Produit</th>
                <th>Image_Produit</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
            //$amount  = $row['amount'] == 0 ? '' : number_format($row['amount']);
            echo '<tr>

                    <td>'.$row['nom'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['description'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['prix'].'</td>
                    <td>'.'<img src='."127.0.0.1/images/".$row['image']." width=100 height=100";'/></td>

                </tr>';
        }?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "*I get all the data and are displayed.The problem is the image can not be displayed*" is the image link from the DB correct? Is the image in the correct location? what does this output `var_dump($row['image']);`? Does the "image" field exist in the table?

Comment: The OP has messed up concatenation here... As you can see, he switches between single and double quotations, and thus there is an issue with that last <td> cell... Also, the image link isn't relative. <td>'.'<img src='."127.0.0.1/images/".$row['image']." width=100 height=100";'/></td>

Comment: I would like to thank all of you :) :) it works

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
   //$amount  = $row['amount'] == 0 ? '' : number_format($row['amount']);
   echo '<tr>
   <td>'.$row['nom'].'</td>
   <td>'.$row['description'].'</td>
   <td>'.$row['prix'].'</td>
   <td><img src="/images/'. $row['image'] . '" width="100" height="100"/></td>
   </tr>';
 }
?>
```

Your image path should be relative, not with 127.0.0.1 on it! You can try src="images/" also if the slack in front messes up. You can also do things like $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] to get the host name for the URL instead of using an IP like 127.0.0.1 :)

The other issue I detected was a problem with the concatenation of your $row['image'] value... You messed up the ' and " symbols around there, so that may be why it's not showing up at all. Either way, I believe my code above fixes your issue!